# Why don't iPhone or iPad compress the video they record?

Tags: video, iphone, compression, ipad

I just recorded 30mins of video on an iPad (1080p, of course) and it took up close to 5Gb. So my question: is it really so hard to do on-the-fly compression? Surely that's what those multi-core CPUs are for. Or am I missing something?

Comment: 30 mins at 1080p, 5GB is actually a pretty good size for that.

Comment: What, what? This question *is* about both computer hardware and software @Xavierjazz

Answer (score 7):

5GB for 30 mins of HD data is already highly compressed - a raw 1080p is stream is in the order of magnitude of 50 times that size. - It seems that your expectations may be unrealistic, or that you need to trade off quality for a smaller filesize.  (Not sure if/how you can do that on an ipad - I suspect you can't - at least not unless you stop recording 1080p).

Also, "On the fly" compression is very CPU intensive, and getting better results requires a lot more CPU and other resources.  Most of the highly compressed stuff you will find on torrent streams etc uses 2 pass compression - where the encoder can spend time analysing frames, looking ahead and stealing bandwidth from relatively static scenes and provide it to scenes with more movement.   Your iDevice can't do that in real time.

Also bear in mind the tradeoff in battery life when the CPU's are "full on".

Answer (score 5):

The ARM CPUs in mobile devices are less powerful than their desktop counterparts even if their frequency is the same (you can't compare them), and even desktops still struggle with on the fly video encoding, that's why you can play a game smoothly at 60 FPS but as soon as you start a screen recording program your frame rate drops significantly (and GPU manufacturers now try to do encoding on the GPU itself to speed that up).

I don't have numbers to back this up (my iPhone isn't jailbroken so I can't run "top" on it and see) but recording video is already quite CPU intensive on a mobile device, so they try to favor quality over compression and as a side effect you end up with large files.

There are third party apps that allow you to record at lower resolutions/frame rates but with better compression rates (smaller files), you can try those.

Comment: To be fair, the quality is pretty awful.